# Dedicated server "out of RAM" while monitoring tool show RAM at 50%

Tags: memory-usage, dedicated-server

I have this dedicated server at OVH with 64gb RAM running several docker containers.

In the last month, it has started to hang unexpectedly;

- Monitoring tool shows memory & cpu usage at barely 50%
- I can't even connect through ssh cause of lack of ram
- When I open a console through KVM, can't even execute an "ls" command as it cant allocate memory

I already made hardware checks and everything looks OK.

What could be causing the system to behave as it had no RAM available, while showing no memory issues on the server monitoring tools? Can I trust those monitoring tools?
I am no sysadmin expert... what would you guys recommend?

Edit: OS is CentOS 7

Thanks

Comment: What operating system version?

Comment: It's a CentOS 7

Comment: Please edit your question with CPU and memory details, such as the output of `cat /proc/meminfo; vmstat 1 1`.  Consider a monitoring tool like netdata to collect this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is the OVH server based on Linux or Windows?

For Linux, create a bash script that will run in the background and log the memory usage every 30 seconds to a file (using 'top' and 'free'). Then when you have a problem, check the log file and see if the server really ran out of memory.

For Windows, you can do same with powershell "Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem". Run it in background, or schedule it with task scheduler.

Comment: Thanks, will try that